# Database connection Mock issue with IDbConnection

Tags: c#, database, nunit, moq

I have written a class where it fetches records and updates the table based on the condition for every interval of time.

I have to write testcases for Database connection, Insertion and Updating values. And i want to do it using moq or any framework given by C#.

I looked into multiple stack-over pages and followed it. However, it didnt work out.

I am trying to mock the database connection at the first place. 
And here is the code.

Trackservice.cs

```
namespace AutocancellationService
{
    public partial class Trackservice : ServiceBase,Servicecalls
    {
        private Servicecalls connectionFactory;

        public Trackservice(Servicecalls connectionFactory)
        {
            this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        }

         public IDbConnection DatabaseConnection()
        {
            var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            cnn.Open();
            return cnn;
        }

        public void Autocancellation(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    ServiceLogFile("Database check :" + DateTime.Now);
                    DatabaseConnection();
                    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        //select and update  
                    }
              }
        }
}
```

Interface for keeping the mocking method -

```
namespace AutocancellationService
{
    public interface Servicecalls
    {
       IDbConnection DatabaseConnection();
    } 
}
```

Test method -

```
    namespace AutocancellationServiceTests
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class AutocancellationServiceTests
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void DatabaseconnectionTest()
            {
                var commandMock = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
                commandMock
                    .Setup(m => m.ExecuteNonQuery())
                    .Verifiable();

                var connectionMock = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
                connectionMock
                    .Setup(m => m.CreateCommand())
                    .Returns(commandMock.Object);

                var ConnectionMock = connectionMock.Object.State.ToString();

                var connectionFactoryMock = new Mock<Servicecalls>();
                connectionFactoryMock
                    .Setup(m => m.DatabaseConnection())
                    .Returns(connectionMock.Object);

                var actual = connectionMock.Object;

             //Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to print connectionMock - I am getting Closed as my connection status. And test case is failing. I tried the connection in my code. It works absolutely fine. Requesting for the assistance.

Comment: You mock the `IDbConnection` object, but never actually open the connection.

Comment: May I know where can I open the IDbConnection. Will it be in Database connection interface method? I request you to help me in getting this resolved.

Comment: I tried Initializing the IDbConnection object and using it in my connection method. And test is still failing for the above code. I am using the connectionMock as "Closed" after converting to String.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi - Problem is about Mocking the Database connection using moq framework and above is the approach which i have tried and couldnt get the expected behavior. Please let me know if you have any approach to perform database connection mocking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NagendraBhat what are you actually trying to do? You appear to be trying to mock and test the interface, which make no sense based on what you are showing.

Comment: Normally, one does not mock the subject under test, which is why I am confused about what it is you are actually trying to achieve by mocking the connection

Comment: I have database connection using which I am performing some select and update based on the condition. So, you are saying i can not test the database connection using mocking? Not possible to mock the database connection to check whether my connection is success/failure? "Subject under test" is the same context here?

Comment: Sure you can mock connection. You setup the property to behave as desired. The shown code is just very confusing and I want to make sure I understand what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: Your shown test code is mocking and testing the mock, which is what makes no sense. All that proves is that the mocking framework works. Hence my confusion about what your actual goals

Comment: @Nkosi Basically, I want to mock the database connection. Please provide me the guidance in mocking it. Lets not consider the above code. Please help me in writing it from the first.

Comment: Testing this would led to connection failure after mocking(var actual). I am getting Connection state as closed so i can not perform any further database transaction as my connection mock itself is wrong.

Comment: @NagendraBhat this is why I was asking so many question before for clarification. if you want to hit the actual database then there is no need for a mock to begin with.